# How does bookmyshow decrypts Whatsapp api to send text?

Tags: api, whatsapp

I am curious to know how Bookmyshow and Redbus decrypts Whatsapp API to send text message via whatsapp ?

Does Whatsapp published their API publically or their technical team decrypt their API ?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 2):

So far WhatsApp has not publicly announced API's. It is not sure if there is any API available for premium customers like Bookmyshow or Redbus.

But you can achieve automated message like how Bookmyshow and redbus does by using **Selenium** combined with **WhatsApp Web.**

WhatsApp has provided a feature called Click to Chat, reference : https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000030/. By this method you can message anyone without having their phone number saved in your phone contacts list.

Click to chat workflow involves

1. Creating a custom URL with user phone number and text message to send
2. Clicking on the Send Button (This will open WhatsApp Web with user phone number provided is selected in WhatsApp Web chat area)
3. Clicking on the send button in chat area of whats app web to send message.

The above 3 steps can be automated using [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) (Web browser automation).

There are lot of articles explaining this method and one such example can be found at https://www.craftedforeveryone.com/whatsapp-send-api-or-click-to-chat-automation-using-selenium-and-c-sharp/

By using Selenium, WhatsApp for Business and WhatsApp Web you can exactly replicate how bookmyshow sends messages.

WhatsApp for Business provides option to set automatic replies by which you can auto respond to the incoming messages.